# Part no: coolant flange/elbow

Tags: cooling-system, renault, water-pump, coolant-leak, clio

I have an '04 1.2L 16v Renault Clio Dynamique with a leaking coolant flange/elbow where the lower coolant line connects to the water pump. You can see where flange is in relation to the pump and coolant lines here:

[image]

And you can see the obvious crack in the plastic flange here:

[image]

Can anyone help me source one of these things so that I can fit a replacement? I feel able to drain all the coolant and fit the thing, I just can't get my hands on one.

Thank you for your help!

Ari

Comment: Renault Dealer parts department or a scrap yard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of hunting I managed to track it down, it's part 7701041346 (or 7701041348 for some older cars) and you can still get it online if you search around for a bit. It'll cost you maybe £30 to buy and it's not hard to drain the coolant and fit it yourself.